# Trying to check my .JSON file for a users ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So my plan is to search the JSON file first and check if the user's ID is in there, if it is it should respond with "You have already registered.", if not then it should continue with the rest of the code.(which is where "data" will be added)

So far I only managed to add the "data" to the JSON file but couldn't figure out how to search for the ID eventually deleting the rest of it to find a solution.

```
@client.command(aliases = ['Register'])
async def register(ctx):  
  data = ctx.author.id, currency, Class, Cards
  with open('Player_Stats.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
  await ctx.send("Account registered!")
```

Comment: Have you tried to compare `data` with the `author.id`?

Comment: Come to think of it.. no I haven't, going to try that right now.

Comment: Ok so, I've tried over and over.. I'm using an if statement but at the point where I'm to start the elif I don't really know how to move.

Comment: Can we see what your json looks like? It'll help us help you a bit more if we can see it 

Comment: My .JSON file just has a pair of square brackets " [] " and whenever someone uses .register it puts the user's ID and a few other stuff like currency that's set to 0 as a default.

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer a database query over a JSON file lookup. If you still want to go with the file you should probably detail the file format. Anyway you will load the file and search for the key or value on the JSON.